# Blocking and unblocking a Facebook user to delete messages on both our end?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I remember before that when you block someone on Facebook, your conversations also disappear. I experienced it firsthand. I had conversations with a person and then all of it suddenly just disappeared. I did not delete the conversation. I wondered why because I'm not blocked, I can see the person's profile and I can start a conversation (and our conversation was gone) but we were no longer friends on Facebook (blocking automatically unfriends). I figured it must be because I was blocked and unblocked immediately after. This is what I want to do.

But I don't know how it works now. The [settings about blocking in Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=blocking) is now multiple. There's different for Facebook and Messenger. What does it do now? Can I do what I described above?

Answer (score -1):

FacebookemailAbuKaraMajdy
a busy cat](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg)
[image: two muppets]

The word in square brackets is the alt text, which gets